# Are there other governments that broke promises to indigenous populations and might be liable to a lawsuit?

Tags: law, canada, indigenous-people

According to the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2024/01/18/canada-indigenous-robinson-treaty-crown/):

> More than 170 years ago, before Canada confederated in 1867,
> Indigenous people in what’s now Northern Ontario signed treaties,
> ceding a vast territory north of Lake Superior and Lake Huron to the
> Crown in exchange for a promise: that the wealth flowing from the land
> would be shared with them. Instead, their descendants argue, the Crown
> has long broken that promise, turning a profit from the minerals
> buried deep beneath the ground and the trees reaching high into the
> sky, while they are shackled by poverty, lack adequate housing and
> suffer poorer health outcomes than non-Indigenous Canadians.
>
> “One treaty partner is getting rich at the expense of the other,” said
> Tangie, chief of Michipicoten First Nation, 144 miles north of Sault
> Ste. Marie, Ontario. “Our elders have always said that the only
> consistent thing about the treaty is that it has never been honored by
> our treaty partner.” Now, that broken promise is at the center of a
> legal fight that’s being closely watched — not just because it could
> end with the largest litigation award in Canada’s history, but also
> because it could dictate how resource is shared with Indigenous people in the future and the role of courts in reconciliation.

Are there other governments that broke promises to indigenous populations and might be liable to a lawsuit?

It seems that it's possible that the Canadian legal system determines that the government owes money to the indigenous population of Canada.

I am wondering if there are other governments who broke similar promises that might also get sued and end up having to pay reparations, beside the United States.

Comment: "I am wondering if there are other governments who broke similar promises that might also get sued and end up having to pay reparations beside the United States." Yes, that might happen. Why not? I'm not sure where exactly you are aiming at? Do you want examples of broken promises? Lists of ongoing lawsuits? Something else?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This question basically asks if any government has been liable to paying reparations to subjects it bargained with but didn't hold to the end of the bargain. In my opinion, this is an important political philosophy issue and deserves more attention and recognition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

1. **ILO Convention 169**

The Indigenous and Tribal Peoples [Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_and_Tribal_Peoples_Convention,_1989) has been adopted by the International Labour Organization in 1989. 27 countries have ratified the convention, recognizing collective legal rights to their Indigenous People, including the right to collective law action.

Signatories include countries where the Rights of Indigenous People are a complex issue (most of Latin America, Denmark, Norway, Nepal...) and some countries where it seems less dramatic (Luxemburg...)

2. **Sami People**

[Sami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1mi_peoples) People are sometimes described as "Europe's last Indigenous People". They live in northern Norway, Sweden, Finland and Russia, and have filled (and won) collective lawsuits in the first three of these countries.

In **Norway**, the [Constitution](https://perma.cc/ZW8F-YTG7) promises Sami People the right to

> preserve and develop their language, culture and way of life.

Reindeer herding is essential to said way of life, yet in [2013](https://www.nhri.no/en/2023/about-the-wind-farms-on-fosen-and-the-supreme-court-judgment/) the Ministry of Petroleum and Energy

> grant[ed] a licence to the Storheia and Roan wind power plants on the Fosen Peninsula. (...) The herders claimed that the construction interfered with their right to enjoy their own culture.

They won in local courts in 2016, and then in the Supreme Court of Norway in 2021. (However the decision has not been upheld on the ground yet and the windmills are [still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosen_Vind#Criticism) in the path of the reindeers...)

In **Sweden**, they won in [2016](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/03/sweden-indigenous-sami-people-win-rights-battle-against-state) a lawsuit in Gällivare district court granting them exclusive rights on hunting and fishing in a given area around the village of Girjas Sameby. Those rights were once recognized but had been stripped by the Sweden Parliament in 1993.

The Swedish Supreme Court [upheld](https://www.dw.com/en/hunting-in-the-arctic-circle-the-sami-vs-the-swedish-state/video-56880844) this decision in 2021.

In **Finland**, disputes about who is eligible to vote for the (state-recognized) Sámi Parliament have reached the UN's Committee on the Elimination of Racial Discrimination which [ruled](https://www.euronews.com/2022/06/15/un-finds-finland-violated-political-rights-of-indigenous-sami-people) in favor of the Sami claimants in 2022.

3. **Inuit Tapiriit Kanatami vs UE**

Inuit communities from Groenland filled a [lawsuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit_Tapiriit_Kanatami_v_Parliament_and_Council) against UE Commission and Parliament about regulations on seal trade that they considered to violate their promised tribal rights. However,

> The General Court rejected the application

for technicalities that I will let the interested reader dig further into.

Generally [speaking](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ethnologie-francaise-2020-3-page-513.html), the complex and multi-layered European Law System is not very favorable to collective indigenous rights.

4. **Mapuche communities vs Chile**

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_and_Tribal_Peoples_Convention,_1989), alas with a broken link as source:

> In November 2009, a court decision in Chile, considered to be a landmark in indigenous rights concerns, made use of the ILO convention law. The court ruled unanimously in favor of granting a water flow of 9 liters per second to Chusmiza and Usmagama communities. The legal dispute had dragged for 14 years, and centers on community water rights in one of the driest deserts on the planet. The Supreme Court decision on Aymara water rights upholds rulings by both the Pozo Almonte tribunal and the Iquique Court of Appeals, and marks the first judicial application of ILO Convention 169 in Chile.

5. **Chagos Islanders**

United Kingdom is leasing [Chagos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagos_Archipelago_sovereignty_dispute) Islands (on whose sovereignty is also claimed by Mauritius) to the US for a military base that required local people to be disloged. They have tried various legal attempts to have the UK or the US condemned on this issue, without success until today.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. New Zealand has a specific process for handling these claims, prior to the legal and/or political negotiation that settles the claims.

The [Waitangi Tribunal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waitangi_Tribunal) is a permanent commission of inquiry that investigates claims made by the various iwi regarding breaches of the Treaty of Waitangi, the agreement by which Māori accepted partnership with the Crown to establish New Zealand as a part of the British Empire.

The Tribunal investigates the historic context of the claim and attempts to determine the truth of the matter to the best of human ability, then provides recommendations to the Crown for how claims may be best settled.

From that point, the settlement is handled by another branch of government, or rarely matters may be passed through the courts.

Notably, the Tribunal has found in a large number of cases that the government acting for the Crown did breach the Treaty, leading to a wide range of political, economic and regulatory changes as well as significant amounts in compensation.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there other governments that broke promises to indigenous
> populations and might be liable to a lawsuit?
>
> I am wondering if there are other governments who broke similar
> promises that might also get sued and end up having to pay
> reparations, beside the United States.

*The U.S. situation*

An essential difference between the United States and most other countries is that under U.S. Constitutional law, the right of the federal government to unilaterally abrogate treaties both with other countries and with Indian Tribes, without honoring the procedures for withdrawing from a treaty in the treaty itself, is expressly recognized as a right of the federal government that cannot be waived.

Thus, in U.S. law, ordinary domestic federal legislation can override a treaty in a manner contrary to the terms of the treaty, and so can a new treaty (possibly a new treaty to which the other signatories of the old treaty are not parties).

The U.S. federal government has used this authority to formally abrogate many of its treaties with indigenous peoples in the U.S., and its courts, has been indifferent about enforcing those treaties with Indian tribes that still remain technically in force.

So, while the U.S. has paid some reparations to Indian tribes with whom it has treaties that it has breached, from time to time, Indian tribes with treaties in the U.S. are actually on much shakier legal ground than in most other countries.

*Countries other than the U.S. and Canada*

In contrast, almost all other countries, as a matter of black letter law, at least, provide that treaties, in general, are superior to ordinary domestic national law, which must yield to the applicable treaty provisions. And, these countries have very strong political norms that mandate that the nation should withdraw from a treaty only as provided for in the treaty, or if it is silent on how that is done, with the consent of all treaty parties who are affected by the withdrawal from the treaty.

In countries with parliamentary supremacy, unilaterally abrogating a treaty is not absolutely forbidden, but the "soft law" of parliamentary political norms strongly discourages parliament from exercising this theoretical authority without very good cause to do so.

This doesn't mean that other countries haven't breached treaties for indigenous peoples. The vast majority of nations with treaties with indigenous peoples have breached one or more of those treaties, either directly or by interpreting a treaty in a bad faith manner or by extracting concessions from existing treaties by duress.

In theory, in countries other than the U.S. that haven't formally abrogated their treaties with indigenous peoples, the indigenous peoples can go to court to seek a remedy to enforce these treaties (in most cases).

This has been done from time to time in various countries around the world. Indigenous peoples are generally on stronger legal footing to do so than they would be in the U.S., and have legal rights closer to those of the indigenous peoples of Canada to enforce their treaties.

But, of course, various legal doctrines from country to country limit the extent to which this is really a viable remedy, and at some point, politics would drive much more powerful non-indigenous populations in these countries to simply ignore treaty obligations that they find to be too burdensome, legal rights be damned.

Comment: Yep, Canada made a mistake back in the day of not incorporating a parliament supremacy clause into their constitution and now they’re paying for it by having to cater to tiny groups.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if there are other governments who broke similar promises that might also get sued and end up having to pay reparations, beside the United States.

Governments that broke promises to indigenous or local populations is a larger category than the governments that can be legally sued for this. One example of the former could be the British government that promised that Syria, Lebanon, Palestine, and Iraq would be parts of the future Arab state, led by King Hussein of Hejaz - see [McMahon - Hussein correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMahon%E2%80%93Hussein_Correspondence) and [Arab revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Revolt):

> **On the basis of the McMahon–Hussein Correspondence, exchanged between Henry McMahon of the United Kingdom and Hussein bin Ali of the Kingdom of Hejaz, the rebellion against the ruling Turks was officially initiated at Mecca on 10 June 1916.** The primary goal of the Arab rebels was to establish an independent and unified Arab state stretching from Aleppo to Aden, which the British government had promised to recognize.
>
> The Sharifian Army, led by Hussein and the Hashemites with backing from the British military's Egyptian Expeditionary Force, successfully fought and expelled the Ottoman military presence from much of the Hejaz and Transjordan. By 1918, the rebels had captured Damascus and proclaimed the Arab Kingdom of Syria, a short-lived monarchy that was led by Hussein's son Faisal I.
>
> **Having covertly signed the Sykes–Picot Agreement with the French Third Republic, the British reneged on their promise to support the Arabs' establishment of a singular Arab state.** Instead, the Arab-majority Ottoman territories of the Middle East were broken up into a number of League of Nations mandates, jointly controlled by the British and the French. Amidst the partition of the Ottoman Empire, the defeated Ottomans' mainland in Anatolia came under a joint military occupation by the victorious Allies, though this was gradually broken by the Turkish War of Independence, which established the present-day Republic of Turkey.

Conflicting to both [Sykes-Picot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) promises to France and McMahon's promises to the Arabs, the British also gave a promise to the Zionist movement, known as [Balfour Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balfour_Declaration), acquiescing to Jewish immigration to Palestine (although not necessarily establishment of a Jewish state), but equally reneged on it - notably [blocking the flight of Jews from Nazi Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Palestine#The_Holocaust_and_immigration_quotas):

> In 1939, as a consequence of the White Paper of 1939, the British reduced the number of immigrants allowed into Palestine. The Second World War and the Holocaust started shortly thereafter and once the 15,000 annual quota was exceeded, Jews fleeing Nazi persecution were interned in detention camps or deported to places such as Mauritius.
>
> [...]
>
> After the war, 250,000 Jewish refugees were stranded in displaced persons (DP) camps in Europe. Despite the pressure of world opinion, in particular the repeated requests of the U.S. President, Harry S. Truman, and the recommendations of the Anglo-American Committee of Inquiry that 100,000 Jews be immediately granted entry to Palestine, the British maintained the ban on immigration.

I doubt though that there is a possibility for British government to be legally pursued for these broken promises by either Palestinians or Holocaust survivors.

Comment: These appear to be specifically examples that are not relevant to the question, which is about those that might be sued over broken promises, not merely breakers.